# Woodstox not report CDATA event type

Tags: java, xml, stax, woodstox

I use woodstox to read xml file but i have a problem the library not notify me when the element read is CDATA. Someone can help me? This is my code and i want to understand where is the error.

```
    XMLInputFactory2 factory = new WstxInputFactory();
    if (factory.isPropertySupported(XMLInputFactory2.P_REPORT_CDATA)) {
        factory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory2.P_REPORT_CDATA, Boolean.TRUE);
    }
    FileReader toRead = new FileReader(source);
    XMLStreamReader2 streamReader =XMLStreamReader2)factory.createXMLStreamReader(toRead);
    while (streamReader.hasNext()) {
            if (streamReader.getEventType() == XMLStreamReader.CDATA) {
                System.out.println("<![CDATA[" + streamReader.getText() + "]]>");
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is buggy. I will actually let you figure out how, as this is really pretty basic issue with using Stax API. Hint: try actually printing out event type, see if you can find something interesting.